# What semantic notions connect 'fold' with 'plight' = predicament?

Tags: etymology, english, vulgar-latin, french

Of the two noun homonyms 'pledge', I'm asking merely about that derived from Latin.    For the other homonym  from Proto-Germanic , please see [this](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/12196/5306). [Etymonline for 'plight (n.1)'](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=plight&searchmode=none) :

> "**condition or state** (usually bad)," late 12c., "danger, harm, strife,"
>   from Anglo-French *plit, pleit*, Old French *pleit, ploit* "condition" (13c.), originally **"way of folding,"**
>   from Vulgar Latin *plictum*,
>   from Latin *plicitum*, neuter past participle of Latin *plicare **"to fold, lay"**,
>    from PIE root [*plek-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*plek-) "to plait".
>
> Originally in neutral sense (as in modern French *en bon plit* "in good condition"),
>   sense of "harmful state" (and current spelling) probably is from convergence and confusion with [*plight* (n.2)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=plight&allowed_in_frame=0)    via notion of "entangling risk, pledge or promise with great risk to the pledger."

1. Please see the titled question.
2. How did a **'way of folding'** (which looks limited to folding clothes) generalise to mean '"**condition or state** (usually bad)'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In English, events *unfold.* In Italian, ***gli eventi prendono una piega,*** i.e. they *get a fold* (usually ***una brutta piega,*** *a bad one,* but that’s how the world goes...) The same thing is referenced by two opposite metaphors. 
Note that for specific persons or processes we have an almost exact English equivalent: ***ha preso una brutta piega*** is a possible traslation of *he/she/it took a bad turn.*

It is not necessary to posit a convergence of the Germanic and the Romance roots. If vulgar Latin used the same metaphor as present-day Italian, the *plic(i)tum,* just like its Italian cognate *piega,* was the fold the events got, and so, by extension, a condition or state. This last step didn’t happen in Italian: we **cannot** say ****È in una brutta piega,*** but it happened in French (*en bon plit* is mentioned by your source) and this is enough to explain the English.

However, I’m afraid that the only way your question and my answer can be considered on-topic in this SE is under the title “what can be guessed about late vulgar Latin from Romance etymologies?”. Therefore, I’ve added the `vulgar-latin` tag to it.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is given, in plain and simple words, in the second paragraph of the quotation from Etymonline *in the question itself*. The semantic expansion happened in English.

When taken together, this; the Dario's account of the parallel development in Italian; the semantics of *complicate,* developed in English and ultimately coming from L. *complicatus,* incl. “confusing;” and the semantics of L. *plexus*, of the same root, “involved, intricate, entangled, ambiguous, confusing”, when taken together, expose the requested metaphoric connection: **"being entangled, bound” > “being in a dangerous or difficult situation.”**

In English, confusion, and eventual convergence into homophony with the second lemma, plight as a solemn pledge, with its implication of being *bound* by the pledge, is unsurprising.